# Node.js writable stream _write() execution in parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, stream

### Question

In Node.js writable-stream, are there any way to call _write() in parallel?

### What I hope & try (& fail)

I hope to execute asynchronous functions in parallel in writable._write with highWaterMark.

I want to upload many files (over 10,000 !!) to cloud in parallel.
Of course, 10,000 parallel upload cause memory overflow, so I plan like below.

```
"filename" Readable-stream => "upload" Writable-steream
                     [highWaterMark](parallel limit)
```

So I test like below.

```
class uploadWritable extends Writable {
  constructor() {
    const options = {
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 10
    };
    super(options);
  }
  _write(filepath, encoding, callback){
    asyncUpload(filepath, callback); // When upload finished, callback is called.
  }
}
```

I expect that
10 "asyncUpload" is called in parapell. And when one of "asyncUpload"s finish, new file is come from readable-stream and start "asyncUpload".
But above code cause "one by one" upload.

### Question

Is above failure because of my code?
Are there any way to execute async function in parallel with Node.js writable-stream?

Comment: Have you tried `Writeable._writev(chunks, cb)` which will be called with all of the buffers currently in the write queue?

Comment: Alternatively, `highland.js` has a parallelizer for streams which ought to work for your case.

Comment: What actually is the callback in this code?